# Angular JS ng-style

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

style attribute is appended to a element based on the expression in ng-style added to the element.Below is the code which adds background color to the Style attribute dynamically.

```
          <div class="legend">
            <span data-ng-repeat="item in history[0].costItems"><i ng-style="{ 'backgroundColor':item.graphColor}"></i><p> {{item.itemLabel}}</p></span>
          </div>
```

item.graphcolor is part of ng-repeat, above (Any tag) div will be looped to display many div's in the screen, but each div will have a different backgroung-color.

It is working fine in the screen with the color,but when printed in PDF it is not visible.Is there a possible way to append '!important' to the background-color in style attribute so that it displays in PDF.

I tried concatenating !important to the style attribute using jQuery, but it was appended in console and shown in the alert box but was not reflected in the style attribute of the element.

I Even tried replacing ';' with '!important;', it dint work as well.

Any other approaches to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My best advice since you didn't give much code is to look at

```
@media print {
    .print_class {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

you might have to get away from using angular directives

```
<div class="legend"> 
    <span data-ng-repeat="item in history[0].costItems">
    <i style="background-color: {{item.graphColor}}"></i>
    <p> {{item.itemLabel}}</p></span>     
</div>
```

Comment: Am trying to get a color from item.graphColor ----> this will tell me the color to be shown as background....but adding a class attribute will display the color which i want.

Comment: ng-class will also dynamically append css but is it still possible to append '!important'..added the code in my question Steven

Comment: What about using 
<div class="legend">
            <span data-ng-repeat="item in history[0].costItems"><i style="background-color: {{item.graphColor}}"></i><p> {{item.itemLabel}}</p></span>
          </div>

Comment: That's correct Steven but it appears only on the screen...i Tried in Chrome  print CSS media option...i added a class and copied the same styles available in Style attribute  and added !important,,,by this way it worked in PDF,,,so i thought appending !important to the styles in the Style attribute will automatically make it appear in PDF,,,tried with scripts to append it,,but no luck

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. If you want to put some code on plnkr I could check it out, but I'm about out of ideas

Comment: This replacing and concatenation which i tried is appended in console,,but when it comes to the element.i have no idea how it is removed...and only the color rgba(254,51,8) is displayed as style='background-color:rgba(254,51,8);'....   '!important' is removed some how